# Building blocks of the president's DNA

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

I'm looking for an old movie I saw a while ago (~2010) that felt as if it was an 80s style knock off comedy sci-fi. I don't remember much about it, or even in what context I saw it (I could have only seen the trailer) but one scene sticks out. The president has been kidnapped/abducted by the aliens and replaced by a clone. The aliens are explaining that they "cloned him using the building blocks of his DNA" where it cuts to a visual gag of actual coloured building blocks.

Several other moments I remember include a scene in an open area with lots of people/aliens where a background character is accosted by guards and killed using a 'dehydrator' or 'dehydration gun', as well as a scene in a busy space shuttle that looks like the inside of a 747, possibly featuring a crying baby and some floating vomit. I also seem to remember a homage to the *Space Odyssey* scene with a floating pen, but that could be from something else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ***[2001: A Space Travesty](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157262/)*** (2000).

> Marshal Dix is to free US president from aliens on the int'l lunar base. A clone has replaced him in The White House. Can Dix prevent an alien invasion?

As [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Travesty) notes, the film has a few scenes parodying *2001: A Space Odyssey*. The floating pen example you mentioned could be a low gravity scene on a space shuttle, set to Johann Strauss II's "The Blue Danube Waltz."

> ***2001: A Space Travesty*** is a 2000 sci-fi comedy film directed by Allan A. Goldstein and starring Leslie Nielsen, Ophélie Winter, Peter Egan, and Ezio Greggio. **The film has a few sequences parodying elements of *2001: A Space Odyssey*, but is not focused on parodying that film alone.** Filming took place in Los Angeles, California.

The DNA building blocks scene occurs early on in the film, when Leslie Nielsen's character is being briefed about the US President's cloning. The blocks shown on-screen look like giant, white Lego bricks.

I didn't notice any mention of a dehydrator/dehydration gun, but there is a scene in a busy lunar airport where an alien disguised as a human is detected by sensors, and then a bunch of guards show up and suck it into what looks a bit like an oversized vacuum cleaner on wheels, within which it explodes due to being exposed to high-pitched sonics.

Comment: yep, that's it. the space shuttle, kidnapped president, comedy. I'll accept when SE lets me